# For a bus schedule, should I have one data table for all busses and store the timetable in a column, or create seperate tables for each bus?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I just need to be able to display the arrival times of the next couple buses, don't plan on doing any trip planning.

Having all the times for each route in a single entry would probably be faster for the database right? Although that would mean whatever's pulling schedules would need to get the whole thing even if they just need a few.

Which way would be more efficient?

Comment: Any option that includes the words "create separate tables for each" is almost certainly the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest form, you need three tables: one for your buses, one for their stops, and one for the timetables.

```
create table bus (
    bus_id int -- primary key
,   route_name varchar(64)
)

create table stop (
    stop_id int -- primary key
,   bus_id int references bus(bus_id)
,   address_or_intersection varchar(128)
)

create table timetable (
    time_entry_id int -- primary key
,   stop_id int references stop(stop_id)
,   run_id int
,   stop_time time
)
```

The first two tables are self-explanatory. Here is an example of the third table for a route with three stops that makes one run in the morning and one run in the evening:

```
bus:
bus_id    route_name
------    ----------
   1      red arrow

stop:
stop_id   bus_id   address
-------   ------   ---------
   1         1     Market St
   2         1     North Point
   3         1     Stockton

timetable:
time_entry_id   stop_id   run_id  stop_time
-------------   -------   ------  ---------
    1              1         1     06:15
    2              2         1     06:39
    3              3         1     07:05
    4              1         2     19:03
    5              2         2     19:30
    6              3         2     19:51
```

Comment: Would it be a problem that there are around 100 bus routes each with around 20-40 stop times? For the timetable I could have another column for bus_id but there'd be about a thousand entries in the single data table, speed wise would it better to have each timetable for each bus in a separate data table?

Comment: @CheapSteaks Four thousand rows is a relatively small table by MySQL's measure: it can handle several orders of magnitude more rows with proper indexing. Chances are, the whole table would fit in memory for lightening-fast performance! You would not get much, if any, speedup by breaking up the table, but you will multiply the maintenance headaches by about one hundred. You do not need bus_id in the timetable, because you have stop_id, and stop_id can be linked to bus_id in a unique way.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you get the third bus (or more)?  I would create a bus table to reference from a main table of routes via foreign key.

HTH, Bud